# server set cookie isn't available

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Browser is not able to get cookie set the proxied response. Request reaches from load-balancer to our node server, further from that node-server we proxy forward(express-http-proxy) to other port. While handling request in other port we set an cookie to "res" object. These cookie aren't going forward to original browser who has invoked for the call.

It seems cookie is getting lost.

I'm also setting explicitly through userResDecorator to set the cookie explicit, but still not getting on browser.